# replace a string in entire dataframe from excel with value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have this kind of data from excel

```
dminerals=pd.read_excel(datafile)
print(dminerals.head(5))
```

[image]

Then I replace the 'Tr' and NaN value using for loop with this script

```
for key, value in dminerals.iteritems(): 
    dminerals[key] = dminerals[key].replace(to_replace='Tr', value=int(1))
    dminerals[key] = dminerals[key].replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=int(0))
```

then print it again, it seems working and print the dataframe types.But it shows object data type.

```
print(dminerals.head(5))
print(dminerals['C'].dtypes)
```

[image]

I tried using this .astype to change one of the column ['C'] to integer but the result is value error

```
dminerals['C'].astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tr'
```

I thought I already change the 'Tr' in the dataframe into integer value. Is there anything that I miss in the process above? Please help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing `Tr` with 1, however there is a `tr` that's not being replaced (this is what you `ValueError` is saying. Remember python is case sensitive. Also, using for loops is extremely inefficient you might want to try using the following lines of code:

```
dminerales = dminerales.replace({'Tr':1,'tr':1}).fillna(0)
```

I'm using `fillna()` which is also better to fill the null values with the specified value `0` in this case, instead of using repalce.